# Can't move button focus to the next row

Tags: swift, tvos, uifocusguide

What I have here is 3 buttons. `Btn2` is disabled. When `Btn1` is focused, I can't move it to `Btn3`.

All what I need is when `Btn2` is disabled, I can move between `Btn1` and `Btn3` by swiping down and up on the TV controller.

```
+----+
|Btn1|
+----+

+----+     +----+
|Btn2|     |Btn3|
+----+     +----+
```

I tried to implement the focus guide, but no luck

```
let focusGuide = UIFocusGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)
focusGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn1.topAnchor).isActive = true
focusGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn3.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

What exact are topAnchor, bottomAnchor etc. about? There is no documentation on this. Please shed some light on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw your questions and I wonder if you found the documentation of Auto Layout Constrants. It does exist.

If you didn’t find the Doc’s about this Class.

Here it is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide

Another tip to help you in the future, if you think is too confusing to do this programatically, try to use Storyboard and do it with Click and Drag “Methodology”.

Basically, you click on your Layout in Interface and Drag to a specific reference to create a constrants.

Don’t need to worry about Methods, Properties and Classes for Constrants.

Happy Coding.